# Why is my Acceptor disconnecting even after it receives a Heartbeat back like it should?

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

Using QuickFIX/J 1.6.3

I'm getting this strange behavior on my QuickFIX/J Acceptor and I quite don't know why. My Acceptor is sending a TestRequest, expecting for a Heartbeat, the Initiator sends me a Heartbeat, but my acceptor is disconnecting anyways saying:

> Timed out waiting for heartbeat

It gets all even more strange when the Initiator tries to logon and the Acceptor doesn't let it saying

> Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

You can see it in the event and the message logs below. Any help is much appreciated.

Also, my Acceptor has the config `CheckLatency=N`. I do this because the Initiator's SendingTime is slightly behind mine.

### Event Logs:

```
20170321-17:22:48: Session FIX.4.2:MY_COMP_ID->MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID schedule is weekly, SUN 00:00:00-UTC - SAT 23:00:00-UTC

20170321-17:22:48: Created session: FIX.4.2:MY_COMP_ID->MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID

20170321-17:25:31: Accepting session FIX.4.2:MY_COMP_ID->MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID from /x.x.x.x:yyyy

20170321-17:25:31: Acceptor heartbeat set to 60 seconds

20170321-17:25:31: Logon contains ResetSeqNumFlag=Y, resetting sequence numbers to 1

20170321-17:25:31: Received logon

20170321-17:25:31: Responding to Logon request

20170321-17:47:49: Sent test request TEST

20170321-17:48:43: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat

20170321-17:48:50: Accepting session FIX.4.2:MY_COMP_ID->MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID from /x.x.x.x:yyyy

20170321-17:48:50: Acceptor heartbeat set to 60 seconds

20170321-17:49:21: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

20170321-17:49:51: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

20170321-17:50:22: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

20170321-17:55:31: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

20170321-17:56:01: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed

20170321-17:56:32: Multiple logons/connections for this session are not allowed
```

### Message Logs

```
8=FIX.4.2 | 9=77 | 35=1 | 34=55 | 49=MY_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:47:49.041 | 56=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 112=TEST | 10=120 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=78 | 35=0 | 34=229 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:47:34.838 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 112=TEST | 10=179 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:48:36.583 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=141 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:49:07.034 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=131 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:49:37.469 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=146 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:50:07.952 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=132 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:55:17.035 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=130 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:55:47.502 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=132 | 

8=FIX.4.2 | 9=85 | 35=A | 34=1 | 49=MY_CUSTOMER_COMP_ID | 52=20170321-17:56:17.985 | 56=MY_COMP_ID | 98=0 | 108=60 | 141=Y | 10=145 |
```

Comment: What version of Quickfix/J are you using?

Comment: @James 1.6.3. I added it to the question as well. Sorry I missed it.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @PetteriPertola Yeah. This is a QuickFIX/J bug. I set `TestRequestDelayMultiplier=1` on my acceptor and the connections stopped acting up.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see if that resolves the problem for me as well. I think you should add it as an answer, and if possible, elaborate on its impact, if it has solved it for you.

Comment: I am also getting the same error in but don't know where to set TestRequestDelayMultiplier=1 and how to regenerate the same error.?

Comment: @jatinGoyal If you check the solution I posted, it says you put it in `session.cfg` or whatever cfg filename you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to exist a QuickFIX/J bug where the Heartbeat timer and the check for logged on status is out of sync.

This solution is not ideal and is more of a workaround:

Set `TestRequestDelayMultiplier=1` on the `Acceptor`'s *session.cfg*. This will give the engine more leeway in time to check the logon status based on heartbeats.